# Regex to split by a Targeted String up to a certain character

Tags: c#, regex

I have an LDAP Query I need to build the domain.

So, split by "DC=" up to a "comma"

**INPUT:**
LDAP://DC=SOMETHINGS,DC=ELSE,DC=NET\account

**RESULT:**
SOMETHING.ELSE.NET

Comment: `string str = @"LDAP://DC=SOMETHINGS,DC=ELSE,DC=NET\account"; 
string str2 = string.Join(".", str.Split("/")[2].Split("\\")[0].Replace("DC=", "").Split(","));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it pretty simple using `DC=(\w*)` regex pattern.

```
var str = @"LDAP://DC=SOMETHINGS,DC=ELSE,DC=NET\account";
var result = String.Join(".", Regex.Matches(str, @"DC=(\w*)")
                                   .Cast<Match>()
                                   .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Comment: @PrisonerZERO well, code snippet I've posted actually **does** work, and yes, I've tried it. For example, you can test it in the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ezR4Tr) - it outputs exactly "SOMETHINGS.ELSE.NET" as was requested in question. If this approach does not work with your actual data - I suspect you have oversimplified sample input you've posted in question so it can significantly differs from your actual data.

Comment: The only portion of the string I have changed was the DC values...but when I run it...it returns and empty string.  odd.

Answer (score 1):

Without Regex you can do:

```
string ldapStr = @"LDAP://DC=SOMETHINGS,DC=ELSE,DC=NET\account";
int startIndex = ldapStr.IndexOf("DC=");
int length = ldapStr.LastIndexOf("DC=") - startIndex;
string output = null;
if (startIndex >= 0 && length <= ldapStr.Length)
{
    string domainComponentStr = ldapStr.Substring(startIndex, length);
    output = String.Join(".",domainComponentStr.Split(new[] {"DC=", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}
```

If you are always going to get the string in similar format than you can also do:

```
string ldapStr = @"LDAP://DC=SOMETHINGS,DC=ELSE,DC=NET\account";
var outputStr = String.Join(".", ldapStr.Split(new[] {"DC=", ",","\\"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Skip(1)
                                .Take(3));
```

And you will get:

```
outputStr = "SOMETHINGS.ELSE.NET"
```